# How to define state?

Tags: reactjs, web

Does anyone have a good definition for **state** in the context of a web app?

And more specifically: what does **state** mean in the context of React - does that differ at all from the first definition?

I see the term state being used a lot in React development but I haven't been able to find a solid, concise definition for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State in the context of both cases (react and web apps) is the same.

### From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_(computer_science))

> In information technology and computer science, a program is described as stateful if it is designed to remember preceding events or user interactions; the remembered information is called the state of the system.

The important part of that quote is ***remember preceding events or user interactions***.

### In a web app

State is typically stored in a database somewhere. The web app retrieves the 'state' (data) from the database, presents a view that allows the user to **interact** with the state, then sends the new 'state' (data) back to the database.

### In react

React can be thought of as presenting the 'state' of an application to the user. Data is retrieved from somewhere, react displays the data (state) to the user, allows the user to modify it, and then sends it back to where it found it (remembering).

However, when people talk about 'state' in the context of react, they are generally referring to the internal representation of the data or interactions that react is holding in memory while the user is busy interacting with it.

A simple react component that holds some state:

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userName: 'Leeloo'
    };

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const name = (this.state.userName === 'Leeloo') ? 'Korben' : 'Leeloo'
    this.setState({
      userName: name
    })

  }

  render() {
    return ( <
      button onClick = {
        this.handleClick
      } > {
        this.state.userName
      } <
      /button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Toggle / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

In the example above, the component creates some state and stores it in a 'state' property of the class.

It is remembering it's internal state.

When the component renders, it looks up the value stored in state and displays it on the button label. When the button is clicked, this.state is updated to 'remember' the event of clicking the button.

In a full featured web app, you would be retrieving data from a database, storing that data in state, allowing the user to interact with it, then sending that data back to the database.

For example, you might display a user profile page, the user changes their name, password, description, etc... You would store the 'state' of all the changes they made on that page until they click a submit button. Then you could gather up all the changes from the components state and send it back to the database for storage (remembering).

Also, you may want to store state in a react component to describe how the appearance of the app should be based on interactions with it. For example, an `InputBox` component may have a hasError state and when true, adds a red border to the component.

Answer (score 1):

General: State is all data currently stored by the application.

In context of React: State is an object that defines - besides props - how a component is rendered. State can be (unlike props) changed by the component itself.